# I can't display selected text in drop down menu structure

Tags: asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, html-select

How do I get this to display **Select Bedrooms** instead of `0` at page load? `Bedrooms` is an integer property.

```html
<select asp-for="Bedrooms" class="form-control">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select Bedrooms</option>
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: please add asp.net-core tag

Comment: can you be more specific, which tag?

Comment: @RonMartinez when editing this question you should be able to add a tag to the question. Your current tags are 'select' and 'drop-down-menu'. You should add 'asp.net-core' there so that experts in that topic can help you with your question.

Comment: Hi @RonMartinez, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get this to display **Select Bedrooms** instead of `0` at page load? Bedrooms is an integer property.

To achieve your requirement, you can try following approaches.

***Approach 1***: set a non-null value for the first option and give/pass initial value for `Bedrooms` from controller or page handler.

```
<select asp-for="Bedrooms" class="form-control">
    <option value="-1" disabled>Select Bedrooms</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

*in controller action*

```
var model = new MyModel { Bedrooms = -1 };

return View(model);
```

***Approach 2***: set `selected` attribute for the first option via jQuery code.

```
$("select option").first().attr("selected", true);

//or set both disabled and selected attributes
//$("select option").first().attr({ disabled: true, selected: true });
```

Test Result

[image]